# Django send progress back to client before request has ended

Tags: python, django, sockets, http

I am working on an application in Django where there is a feature which lets  the user share a download link to a public file. The server downloads the file and processes the information within. This can be a time taking task therefore I want to send periodic feedbacks to the user before operations has completed. For instances, I would like to inform the user that file has downloaded successfully or if some information was missing from one of the record e.t.c.
I was thinking that after the client app has sent the upload request, I could get client app to periodically ask the server about the status. But I don't know how can I track the progress a different request.How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

1. At first the progress task information can be saved in rdb or redis。
2. You can return the id of the task when uses submit the request to start task and the task can be executed in the background context。
3. The background task can save the task progress info in the db which you selected.
4. The app client get the progress info by the task id which the backend returned and the backend get the progress info from the db and push it in the response.
5. The  interval of the request can be defined by yourself.